# Python mutiledimensional array and concaconate/ append

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following scenario

```
array = np.ndarray(size=(100, 100), dtype = int)  #this should be an empty array of this size

newarray =  np.ndarray(size=(100, 100), dtype = int)


def function1(parameter1, parameter2)
    
    for i in range(50):
    
       function2(pm1, pm2)


def function2(parameter3, parameter4)

      function3(pm3, pm4)


def function3(parameter4, parameter5)
  
    if (statement):
       input = array of 100 column #input is a array of (100, 0) size 
    else:
       input1 = array of 100 column   #input1 is a array of (100, 0 ) size 

     if (statement):
       input3 = array of 100 column #input is a array of (100, 0) size 
    else:
       input4 = array of 100 column   #input1 is a array of (100, 0 ) size
```

I have trouble in making mental model here. My question is how do we add/append our input arrays(which is of (100, 0)) which is in function3 here so that the array(first one at the beginning) above will be array of size (100, 100). This array of size (100, 100) will have the rows as input or input1 and input3 or input4 of size (100, 0) .If this is not possible.

How do we store the arrays of size (100, 0) into a array of size (100, 100).

Answer (score 0):

We don't usually use `np.ndarray`.  `arr=np.zeros((100,100),int)` is the preferred way of initializing an array of a given size and dtype.

`#` is the comment character in Python.

Having created such an array, assign new values to a row  (or rows) with:

```
arr[0,:] = np.arange(100)
arr[1:4,:] = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,100))
etc
arr[4:10,:] = np.arange(600).reshape(6,100)
```

Better yet figure out a way of creating the whole array at once.

```
arr = np.arange(100)[:,None] *  np.arange(100)
```

I think reading the basic numpy introduction will get you started.